# Propel Nested Set Undelete Soft Deleted

Tags: propel, nested-sets

I use propel and soft delete and propel nested set.

- When I delete a node without children and then do `$node->undelete()` everything is fine, node is recovering from soft delete.
- But if a node have children and delete it then if I do `$node->undelete()` it recovers only the node without any children....

Any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the `undelete()` method is pretty simple, all it does it nullify the `deleted_at` column on that exact table. However, if you have the soft delete behavior on the sub table as well, then you could do this:

```
SubTableQuery::create()
  ->includeDeleted()
  ->filterByParentId($parentRecord->getId())
  ->unDelete();
$parentRecord->unDelete();
```